# Handling typescript when passing functions between parent & child

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have A Component Called `ParamsPicker.tsx` which render multiple input components and Hold's their state

```js
import React from 'react';
more import...

export enum Assets {
    First,
    Second
}

export interface IParameters {
    id: string
    startDate: string //ISO format
    endDate: string //ISO format
    startTime: string //TimeSpan
    endTime: string //Timespan
    asset: Assets //First / Second
  }

const ParamsPicker = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [selectedParams, setSelectedParams] = React.useState({
        id: '',
        startDate: '', 
        endDate: '', 
        startTime: '', 
        endTime: '', 
        asset: Assets.First,
    });
    const handleChange = (key: string, value: Partial<IParameters>) => {
        setSelectedParams({
            ...selectedParams,
            [key]: value
        });
    };
    console.log(selectedParams)
    return (
        <form className={classes.root} noValidate>
            <Paper elevation={3} square={false}>
                <Grid className={classes.container}>
                    <Typography className={classes.textStyle}>Select Asset</Typography>
                    <AssetSelector handleParentChange={handleChange} /> //Error Here!
                    <Typography className={classes.textStyle}>Select Start Date & Time</Typography>
                    <DateAndTimePickers label={'Session Starts at 08:30AM'} />
                    <Typography className={classes.textStyle}>Select End Date & Time</Typography>
                    <DateAndTimePickers label={'Session Ends at 15:15PM'} />
                    <FormButton />
                </Grid>
            </Paper>
        </form>
    )
}

export default ParamsPicker

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    some styles....
);
```

On the Input Component Called `AssetSelector` I'm passing a `handleParentChange` function to change
the parent state

This is My AssetSelector component

```js
import React from 'react';
more imports...


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
some styles...
);

interface Props {
    handleParentChange: (key: string, value: Assets) => void
}

const AssetsSelector = (props: Props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [asset, setAsset] = React.useState<IParameters['asset']>(Assets.ES);

    const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
        setAsset(event.target.value as IParameters['asset'])
        props.handleParentChange('asset', asset);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl} required={true}>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Asset</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
                    value={asset}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    label="Asset"
                    defaultChecked={true}
                >
                    <MenuItem value={Assets.First}>First</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={Assets.Second}>Second</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AssetsSelector
```

Everything is working fine, the function does its job, the only problem I have is with typescript
Im getting an `Error` inside the parent component on the `AssetSelctor **handleParentChange**={handlechange}` which tells me that my values don't match

Error:

```
Type '(key: string, value: Partial<IParameters>) => void' is not assignable to type '(key: string, value: Assets) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'Assets' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<IParameters>'.
```

I tried using multiple typescript utils but with no luck,
**The `value` property in `handleChange` should be able to receive the value of each field inside `IParameters`**
Anyone knows what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because `handleChange` has type of `(key: string, value: Partial<IParameters>) => void` while `AssetsSelector` accepts `handleParentChange` with a type of `(key: string, value: Assets) => void`. They should match each other

Comment: Yes, I can read the error, But I can't make them similar because I'm going to pass through different types of values to `handleChange`, I want to make the value there dynamic

Comment: using `any` would make it work, but that is not recommended. You should read about [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Comment: using `any` is never a solution, it cancels the whole point of using  typescript

Comment: that's why generics is included in the comment too

Comment: sorry, I read it still don't know what I'm missing

Comment: `function handleChange: <T>(key: string, value: T) => { ... };`
and
`handleParentChange: <T>(key: string, value: T) => void`

would work. But that won't give you any type safety.

What I would actually recommend is to not create a generic `handleChange` but something like `handleAssetsChange` which only accepts assets and sets them, the child component would be simplified as well. Besides, you should also split the current state into several different, that would help maintain components easily and also you wouldn't need the keys part